# How can I point stack at docker daemon started without using the socket file?

Tags: haskell, docker, haskell-stack

If we start the docker daemon with a flag such as `-H 1.2.3.4:7777`, the `/var/run/docker.sock` file doesn't get created and various `stack` operations such as `stack docker pull` fail:

`$ stack docker pull
Pulling image from registry: 'tweag/haskellr:latest'
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/create?fromImage=tweag%2Fhaskellr%3Alatest: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
Could not pull Docker image:
    tweag/haskellr:latest
There may not be an image on the registry for your resolver's LTS version in
stack.yaml`

How can we tell `stack` to use the daemon at the specific host instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was initially asked on [GitHub](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/972). The answer is is to set `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable, for example with `DOCKER_HOST="1.2.3.4:7777"`.

Comment: You can also add to the docker command the host info: docker -H 1.2.3.4:7777 run ....